# Why does react-native run-ios require defining udid?

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli

On my colleague's laptops, they can run `react-native run-ios --device` and it will run it on the device connected to their laptop. On my laptop, for some reason is also detects my own laptop as a target:

```
$ react-native run-ios --device
Scanning folders for symlinks in /Users/work/.../node_modules (12ms)
Found Xcode workspace xxx.xcworkspace
Could not find device with the name: "true".
Choose one of the following:
Test iPhone iOS 11 Udid: 2b4cbaf...
Sampo’s MacBook Pro Udid: 71C7405...

$ react-native --version
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.52.1
```

In order to run on the device on my laptop I have to use `--udid 2b4cbaf…`. I don't have any emulators running at that time.

Is this a bug in the cli or some misconfiguration on my laptop?

Comment: If you start simulator before running the command manually it should detect the running simulator and run the app on that one.

Comment: I'm trying to run on the attached device. I have no emulators running.